# Flask with uWSGI: Can't set as system service on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, flask, uwsgi

Probably like a lot of folks, I'm trying to follow the tutorial on Digitalocean for setting up a Flask app, a uWSGI instance, and ultimately serve it with nGinx.  I'm trying to set this up on a VM in an Azure environment running Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-uswgi-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-18-04

I'm stuck on step 5.  I can't for the life of me figure out why I can't successfully start my uWSGI instance as a system service due to a 203 permissions error.  I was able to get the uWSGI instance and the Flask app to work together in a virtual environment and hit a test page at http://127.0.0.1:5000/.

I first tried constructing the service and pointing to the ini file I have in my /home/user folder.  I subsequently read that SELinux might be blocking the binary if it is placed in the /home/ folder, so I moved all contents of this operation to my /usr/local/bin folder, but I still can't start the service.  I've chmod'd all files in the folder in question so that my user has full 777 permissions.

**My service file (radioland.service):**

```
[Unit]

Description=uWSGI instance to serve myproject

After=network.target



[Service]

User=azureuser

Group=www-data

WorkingDirectory=/usr/local/bin/radioland/radioland/

Environment="PATH=/usr/local/bin/radioland/radioland/bin"

ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/radioland/radioland --ini radioland.ini



[Install]

WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**My radioland.ini file:**

```
[uwsgi]
module = wsgi:app

master = true
processes = 5

socket = myproject.sock
chmod-socket = 660
vacuum = true

die-on-term = true

logto = /usr/local/bin/radioland/radioland/myproject.log
```

**Permissions (I'm just running this under the 'azureuser' username):**

```
total 52
drwxr-xr-x 7 azureuser azureuser  4096 Sep 10 23:28 .
drwxrwxrwx 7 azureuser www-data   4096 Sep  9 20:00 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 azureuser azureuser 12288 Sep  9 19:18 .radioland.ini.swp
drwxrwxr-x 2 azureuser azureuser  4096 Sep  8 16:24 __pycache__
drwxrwxr-x 3 azureuser azureuser  4096 Sep  8 06:35 flaskr
drwxrwxr-x 2 azureuser azureuser  4096 Sep  8 06:35 instance
drwxrwxr-x 6 azureuser azureuser  4096 Sep 10 06:47 myprojectenv
-rw-rw-r-- 1 azureuser azureuser   546 Sep  8 16:24 myscript.py
-rwxr-xr-x 1 azureuser azureuser   191 Sep 10 23:20 radioland.ini
drwxrwxr-x 6 azureuser azureuser  4096 Sep  8 06:35 venv
-rw-rw-r-- 1 azureuser azureuser    79 Sep  8 16:04 wsgi.py
```

**Finally, the error I always receive (including when changing the username to root):**

```
radioland.service - uWSGI instance to serve myproject
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/radioland.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2021-09-10 23:40:17 UTC; 2h 30min ago
    Process: 127087 ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/radioland/radioland --ini radioland.ini (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)
   Main PID: 127087 (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)

Sep 10 23:40:17 RadioLandVM systemd[1]: Started uWSGI instance to serve myproject.
Sep 10 23:40:17 RadioLandVM systemd[127087]: radioland.service: Failed to execute command: Permission denied
Sep 10 23:40:17 RadioLandVM systemd[127087]: radioland.service: Failed at step EXEC spawning /usr/local/bin/radioland/radioland: Permission denied
Sep 10 23:40:17 RadioLandVM systemd[1]: radioland.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=203/EXEC
Sep 10 23:40:17 RadioLandVM systemd[1]: radioland.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

I am totally lost.  I can't point to anything else on the server that would be blocking the service from starting.

Comment: how about the permissions on all the folders on the way? /usr , /usr/local , /usr/local/bin ..?

Answer (score 0):

According to your log, I believe that the file `/usr/local/bin/radioland/radioland` doesn't have the executable flag. This also causes **Permission Denied** on Linux.

You could try to:

```
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/radioland/radioland
```